# run my .feature files using multiple userdata possibilities

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automated-tests, python-behave

i'm running my .feature files with userdata
what i'm trying to do is to add multiple values in userdata
and loop the execution on every value
for exemple: running login test many times with a different username and password in every try but with one command line

```
Feature: login 

    Scenario Outline : authentification  
        Given open application
        When enter user data
         |username  | password |
        And click on button Log In
        Then user connected
```

```
[behave.userdata]
username1= test
password1= test
username2= automation
password2= automation
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using it like this:

```
Feature: login 

    Scenario Outline : authentification  
        Given open application
        When enter user email and password
        And click on button Log In
        Then user connected
Examples:
   |email | passsword |
   |test   | test      |
   |automation | automation|
```

Comment: using userdata is a must in our project